# open VIM with default code

Tags: vim

I don't know if it's correct to ask this question here. I am a programming enthusiastic and have recently started competitive programming. The problem I face recently is for every question I have to type this whole code almost 25 times a day.

```
#include <iostream>

//other headers or macros go here

using namespace std;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

I have searched for this question on google but couldn't find the answer. Though it's not a programming question there are many competitive coders out there who use vim or VI as their default text editor and would be benefitted by knowing the answer for this question.

Also it would be much better if the method you propose doesn't slow down opening of vim by great factor
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a macro/abbr to do this for you, but you can also make this an `autocmd` to write to a file of a particular type.  There may be a better way to do this, but this is something you would only have to include in your `.vimrc`

```
autocmd FileType c call IoStream()
fu! IoStream()
    if line("$") == 1
        call append(0, "#include <iostream>")
        call append(1, "")
        call append(2, "//other headers or macros go here")
        call append(3, "")
        call append(4, "using namespace std;")
        call append(5, "")
        call append(6, "int main(){")
        call append(7, "    return 0;")
        call append(8, "}")
    endif
endfu
```

Comment: Your answer does solve the purpose, but the disadvantage is it takes O(n) for an update. I mean say if I want to insert a new header then I should change the line numbers of all lines after, to make it look decent. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

1- You can use `vim-templates` [plugin](https://github.com/aperezdc/vim-template). And after installing you must use `:Template *.c` to load templates for `c` language.

2- The second way is to use `au` command:(You can add commands bellow to `.vimrc` file)

```
au BufNewFile *.c 0r ~/.vim/contest.c | let IndentStyle = "c"
au BufNewFile *.cpp 0r ~/.vim/contest.cpp | let IndentStyle = "cpp"
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this in a more generic way, I suggest you maintain snippets that you use often, try the `vim-snippets` plugin:

https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets

https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate

You can also simply copy a `skeleton.c` file but it's not as convenient as snippets

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to type some templated code very quickly, there's no need to install any extra plugins. Just use an insert mode abbreviation in your `.vimrc`.

```
:iab CPPMAIN 
\#include <iostream><CR>
\<CR>
\using namespace std;<CR>
\<CR>
\<CR>int main(){
\<CR>
\<CR>}
```

If you put this into your `.vimrc`, whenever you are in insert mode and type the string `CPPMAIN` followed by a carriage return, it will substitute in the template.

Answer (score 0):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.